# Could not resolve host: Docker for Mac

Tags: docker, dockerfile, aws-cli

While trying to build docker image the build process fails as its unable to resolve some url like github, aws

```
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: awscli.amazonaws.com
```

As part of build process, I am running this script

```
#!/bin/bash

curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.0.30.zip -o awscliv2.zip
unzip awscliv2.zip
```

Dockerfile Snippet

```
FROM docker:20.10.5

ENV AWS_CLI_VERSION="2.1.29"
ENV BIN_PATH="/usr/local/bin"

COPY extra /extra

RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
  apk add --no-cache python3 python3-dev bash git openssh-client openssl ca-certificates tar wget unzip py3-pip curl && \
  pip3 install --upgrade pip && \
  /extra/aws-cli/aws-cli.sh && \
  rm -rf /extra
```

Docker for Mac Daemon Configuration:

[image]

Also, able to ping this URL locally from my Mac Terminal - so the endpoint is reachable and resolvable from my machine

```
kumarvivek@Kumars-MBP infrastructure-developer-tools % ping awscli.amazonaws.com
PING awscli.amazonaws.com (13.225.80.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=246 time=13.288 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=12.282 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=13.152 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=246 time=12.191 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=11.960 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=5 ttl=246 time=12.090 ms
64 bytes from 13.225.80.2: icmp_seq=6 ttl=246 time=11.905 ms
^C
--- awscli.amazonaws.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 11.905/12.410/13.288/0.527 ms
```

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong here? Is there any specific configuration required in docker?

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @MustafaGüler added more snippet of Dockerfile in question, its just a very basic docker image some basic lib and packages.

Comment: Can you ping `awscli.amazonaws.com` . Is it working on your local?

Comment: @MustafaGüler yes I can ping awscli.amazonaws.com locally. Updated the question with ping response locally from mac terminal.

Comment: Can you ping `8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @BMitch yes I can ping 8.8.8.8